# VBA: run-time error '1004' when I use worksheet and variable delaration

Tags: vba, excel, object, variable-declaration

```
Public ws As Worksheet
Public Const Mpath As String = "H:\BankingGrp\MM Board rates\"

Dim USDON As Long, USDTN As Long, USDSN As Long, USD1W As Long, _
    USD2W As Long, USD3W As Long, USD1M As Long, USD2M As Long, _
    USD3M As Long, USD6M As Long, USD9M As Long, USD12M As Long


Sub Record()
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Mpath & Format(Date, "DD") & " " & _
               Format(Date, "MMM") & " " & Format(Date, "YYYY") & ".xls"
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BOARD RATE")
```

Should I use a Range declaration and use  "Set USDON = Range("B15")" instead?

```
USDON = ws.Range(“B15”).Value
USDTN = ws.Range(“D17”).Value
USDSN = ws.Range(“F19”).Value
USD1W = ws.Range(“D21”).Value
USD2W = ws.Range(“D23”).Value
USD3W = ws.Range(“D25”).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, what happens if you *do* try that? [Edit] to let us know! (Don't expect people to try stuff you suggest as possible solutions in the question itself.)

Comment: If it's failing on the literal assignment, then it's because the range object itself doesn't exist or is otherwise inaccessible. Changing your variables to `Range` type will not prevent the error. Is the worksheet protected?

Answer (score 0):

Your double quotes symbols are incorrect. They are not standard double quotes, but angled quotes. For example, `USDON = ws.Range(“B15”).Value` should become `USDON = ws.Range("B15").Value` (notice the quote symbols around `B15` have changed slightly).

Instead, your assignments should become:

```
USDON = ws.Range("B15").Value
USDTN = ws.Range("D17").Value
USDSN = ws.Range("F19").Value
USD1W = ws.Range("D21").Value
USD2W = ws.Range("D23").Value
USD3W = ws.Range("D25").Value
```